# Is GCC inline asm goto supported in the m68k-elf target?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, 68000

I'm working on a project with lots of C wrappers around M68000 asm calls. A few of these calls return a success/fail status on the condition code register, so it would be ideal to 'goto' a C label depending on the status of CC. However, no matter what permutations I try, I am constantly getting syntax errors from the compiler.

(This is gcc 10.2.0 --with-cpu=​m68000)

Example code:

```
  asm(R"(
  moveq #0, d1
  jsr %p0
  bcc %l0
2:
    )":
        :
      "i"(_BURAM),
        "d"(d0_fcode),
        "a"(a0_info),
        "a"(a1_data)
        :
        "cc"
        : failed);

  return true;

  failed:
  return false;
```

The error this generates is:

```
/home/ryou/Projects/megadev/lib/sub/bram.h: In function 'bram_brmwrite':
/home/ryou/Projects/megadev/lib/sub/bram.h:156:7: error: expected ')' before ':' token
  156 |   "cc"
      |       ^
      |       )
  157 |   : failed);
      |   ~
/home/ryou/Projects/megadev/lib/sub/bram.h:144:5: note: to match this '('
  144 |  asm(R"(
      |     ^
```

I have attempted doing it with the simplest of examples, for testing:

```
asm("bra %l0" :::: failed);
```

And I still get:

```
/home/ryou/Projects/megadev/lib/sub/bram.h:144:18: error: expected ')' before '::' token
  144 |  asm("bra %l0" :::: failed);
```

The only other somewhat relevant information I have found here is:
[Extended asm with goto, including an example from the gcc docs, fails to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009974/extended-asm-with-goto-including-an-example-from-the-gcc-docs-fails-to-compile)

However, as you can see in both examples, I am not using any outputs. I assume that the m68k-elf target does not support this in particular, but I really don't see why it wouldn't and I haven't found any documentation saying as much.

There are ways around this (namely by checking the state of CC within the asm snippet itself and pushing the status to an output register), but if at all possible I'd like to use goto labels. Any help with solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is supported.  I think the problem is your code, which has a couple of errors:

1. To use the goto feature, you need to start the inline assembly statement with the `asm goto` keywords.  You are missing the `goto`.
2. The label operands are numbered sequentially after the input operands (and of course there cannot be outputs).  So `failed` is operand 4, and therefore you need to refer to it with `bcc %l4`, not `%l0`.

With these changes I'm able to compile the code.

---

By the way, I don't know much about m68k assembly, but it looks like you are clobbering register `d1`, along with whatever the `_BURAM` subroutine clobbers, yet those have not been declared as clobbers.  Shouldn't you add `"d1"` and the rest along with `"cc"`?

Also, it seems like maybe you are expecting the operands `d0_fcode`, `a0_info`, etc, to be put in those specific registers, presumably because `_BURAM` expects them there.  Do you have those variables defined [`register asm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables) to tell the compiler about that, e.g. `register int d0_fcode asm("d0");`?  Otherwise it could for instance choose `d4` for the `d0_fcode` operand.  In my test it happens by chance that they get put in the desired registers, without explicitly asking, but that is not safe to rely on.

Comment: It's also possible to refer to the target label by name (*you can reference labels using the actual C label name enclosed in brackets*).  That way you don't have to count the number of parameters, or re-work everything if you add or remove something.

Comment: Wow. My brain *completely* glossed over the 'goto' qualifer after the asm command. That was the issue entirely. Thank you!

As for the rest, I had retyped the code in a bunch of different ways to make sure it wasn't syntax, so it was in a pretty weird state when I posted examples. I should have checked the examples better. I'll be referring to labels via the [] brackets. The clobber list too was in a bad state as posted. I do indeed have the variables correctly associated with registers above, I didn't didn't include in the example. You're correct on everything, and thank you again!